# Binary Tree, Binary Search Tree, Binary search

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to understand the Binary tree and referring to online material , and questions asked in SO.

I understood that:

**Binary tree** -> Tree in which each node can have at most 2 nodes.

**Binary search tree** -> Specialized form of Binary tree in which left node value < parent node and right node value > parent node

Do we have a thing called as **Binary search** ?

If **Binary search tree** is a data structure, why it has "search" in it? It gives a feeling as if it is an algorithm?

I am still not clear, can anyone help clear the doubts.

**EDIT**

This is not duplicate of the SO question appearing, it is about asking 'search' leading to misnomer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between binary tree and binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380231/difference-between-binary-tree-and-binary-search-tree)

Comment: My question is about binary search tree, the misnomer , this is not duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a searching algorithm called **Binary search** which performs in O(log n). The Binary search tree is a data structure that seeks to facilitate searching (Binary search) since node values are ranked in this order: left < parent < right. 
However a binary search tree could be unbalanced which means that `difference of height between left child and right child > 1`. Enters more efficient (in terms of searching performance) binary search trees called **Self-balancing binary search tree** that automatically adjust its height following insertions and deletions.

Comment: Also note that the data for a Binary search must be organized (ascending order, descending order etc).